# Trying to access Mod Message of a removed user from Inbox shows the "Oops! Something Bad Happened" error message

Tags: bug, notifications, moderator-tools, global-inbox

Mods get a notification in their inbox every time a Mod message has been sent.[This user](https://superuser.com/users/227777) was initially sent a Mod Message, and then later on removed.

Now, when I try to access the Mod message via the inbox, I get

> Oops! Something Bad Happened!

error message. I'd be expecting a 404 or be shown the message, instead of the error message

Comment: Reproduced on Stack Overflow on a mod message that was still accessible as of Tuesday.

Comment: -1, I can't replicate this issue because I'm not a mod. Please grant me mod privileges so I can verify this bug.